# Why missing \endcsname with tikz-cd when using babel?

Tags: babel, tikz-cd

Why do I get the error `Missing \endcsname inserted` at line 15?

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  f \arrow[d, "\partial"] \\
  g
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Again I get the error if instead of option `russian` I use:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german,main=english]{babel}
```

As the commented-out preamble lines show, I tried to invoke package `csquotes`, in two different ways, to avoid the problem, but that failed, too.

I do *not* get the error with `babel` option `french` however, as in:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}
```

Comment: This is probably due to an active `"` character. It should work if you add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` (it does for me in both cases you cited).

Comment: @frougon: That did it, thank you. Please convert your comment to an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most probably due to an active `"` character. It should work if you add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`.

With `babel`, when the selected language is `french`,<sup>1</sup> the `"` character is not active, however it *is* when you select `german` or `russian`. Active characters very often cause problems when parsing (especially characters that are active for some people or in particular conditions, but not in others). This certainly explains the differences you saw between the three languages.

The `babel` Ti*k*Z library, activated with `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`, allows to avoid these problems in most situations. Quote from the [Ti*k*Z & PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (section *Handling Catcodes and the Babel Package*):

> Inside a Ti*k*Z picture, most symbols need to have the category code 12 (normal text) in order to ensure that the parser works properly. This is typically not the case when packages like `babel` are used, which change catcodes aggressively.
>
> To solve this problem, Ti*k*Z provides a small library also called `babel` (which can, however, also be used together with any other package that globally changes category codes). What it does is to reset the category codes at the beginning of every `{tikzpicture}` and to restore them at the beginning of every node. In almost all cases, this is exactly what you would expect and need, so I recommend to always load this library by saying `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

You can easily determine when the character `"` is active. Just add `\show"` at the place where you want to do the test. If the character is non-active, TeX will print something like:

```latex
> the character ".
l.16 \show"
```

On the other hand, if it's active, you should see something more resembling to this:

```latex
> "=macro:
->\active@prefix "\active@char" .
l.16 \show"
```

Yes, an active character is a macro. TeX expands it just like other macros defined with `\def` (actually, using `\def` *is* the normal TeX way to give a definition to an active character).

Characters that are active for some people and non-active for other people cause problems when they are part of parsed input, because for TeX, an active `"` (i.e., a `"` character token with catcode 13) is a different token from an “ordinary one” (a `"` character token with catcode 12). Parsers must do special handling in order to make TeX treat them the same way in a given context (things like using `\scantokens`).

---

**Footnote**

1. When `babel` isn't loaded, or when it is loaded but the selected language is `english`, the `"` is not active either under normal conditions.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation (as well as the solution)!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. :-)